# ActivityResult API dependency conflict

Tags: android, onactivityresult

I am using this dependencies for ActivityResult API as recommended in documatation:

```
    implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.2.0-alpha02"
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.0-alpha02"
```

but it gives me the following error:

```
            In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[1.2.0
        -rc02]", but isn't being resolved to that version. Behavior exhibited by the library will be unknown.

        Dependency failing: androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.2.0-rc02 -> androidx.fragment:fragment@[1.2.0-rc02], but fragment v
        ersion was 1.3.0-alpha02.

        The following dependencies are project dependencies that are direct or have transitive dependencies that lead to the art
        ifact with the issue.
        -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@20.1.0
        -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api@{strictly 17.2.1}
        -- Project 'app' depends onto androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment@{strictly 2.1.0}
        -- Project 'app' depends onto androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx@{strictly 2.1.0}
        -- Project 'app' depends onto androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4@1.0.0
        -- Project 'app' depends onto androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx@{strictly 2.1.0}
        -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier@{strictly 17.0.0}
        -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@17.0.0
        -- Project 'app' depends onto androidx.fragment:fragment@1.3.0-alpha02
        -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.material:material@1.2.0
        -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.material:material@1.0.0
        -- Project 'app' depends onto androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions@2.1.0
        -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@{strictly 17.0.0}
        -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-iid-interop@{strictly 17.0.0}
        -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-places-placereport@{strictly 17.0.0}
        -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@{strictly 17.0.0}
        -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@{strictly 20.1.0}
        -- Project 'app' depends onto androidx.appcompat:appcompat@1.2.0
        -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-location@{strictly 17.0.0}
        -- Project 'app' depends onto androidx.fragment:fragment@{strictly 1.3.0-alpha02}
        -- Project 'app' depends onto androidx.fragment:fragment-testing@{strictly 1.2.0-rc02}
        -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics@{strictly 17.2.1}
        -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector@{strictly 18.0.0}
        -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-location@17.0.0
        -- Project 'app' depends onto androidx.fragment:fragment@1.2.0-rc02
        -- Project 'app' depends onto androidx.appcompat:appcompat@{strictly 1.2.0}
        -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api@{strictly 17.2.1}
        -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-common@{strictly 19.3.0}
        -- Project 'app' depends onto org.koin:koin-android-scope@{strictly 2.1.6}
        -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.material:material@{strictly 1.2.0}
        -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@{strictly 17.0.0}
        -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl@{strictly 17.2.1}
        -- Project 'app' depends onto androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2@{strictly 1.0.0}
        -- Project 'app' depends onto androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions@{strictly 2.1.0}
        -- Project 'app' depends onto androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx@2.1.0
        -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement@{strictly 17.2.1}
        -- Project 'app' depends onto androidx.fragment:fragment-testing@1.2.0-rc02
        -- Project 'app' depends onto org.koin:koin-android-viewmodel@2.1.6
        -- Project 'app' depends onto org.koin:koin-android-viewmodel@{strictly 2.1.6}
        -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics@17.2.1
        -- Project 'app' depends onto androidx.navigation:navigation-ui@{strictly 2.1.0}
        -- Project 'app' depends onto androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4@{strictly 1.0.0}
        -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk@{strictly 17.2.1}
        -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@{strictly 17.0.0}
        -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats@{strictly 17.0.0}
        -- Project 'app' depends onto androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx@{strictly 1.2.0-rc02}
        -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-datatransport@{strictly 17.0.3}
        -- Project 'app' depends onto androidx.appcompat:appcompat@1.1.0
        -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base@{strictly 17.2.1}
        -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@{strictly 20.0.2}
        -- Project 'app' depends onto androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx@2.1.0

        For extended debugging info execute Gradle from the command line with ./gradlew --info :app:assembleDebug to see the dep
        endency paths to the artifact. This error message came from the google-services Gradle plugin, report issues at https://
        github.com/google/play-services-plugins and disable by adding "googleServices { disableVersionCheck = false }" to your b
        uild.gradle file.
```

who knows how to save it?